# How recent is the use of "so" as in "I'm so full", and did it originate in US or UK English?

Tags: etymology, intensifying-adverbs

On another site somebody has claimed that "so" in constructions like "I'm so full" is "modern California-style young people's colloquial English".

But is it? I'm over 50, I'm a native English speaker, and I'm not American. It doesn't strike me as recent or American, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Linquists refer to the [recency illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recency_illusion) where a usage is thought to be newer than it is; it is particularly common for usages that someone doesn't like.

Comment: @JamesRandom: Yes that was one of my theories of what was happening.

Comment: I’m aware that this should probably be a comment, but I haven’t got the reputation points to make it one. If you want to hear a really good in-depth exploration of the word “so” by a reputable linguist, I’d recommend checking out this episode (https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/lexicon-valley/id500673866?mt=2&i=1000422867635) of John McWhorter’s podcast, Lexicon Valley. He goes into a whole bunch of different ways it’s used and why - the episode overall is about starting sentences with “so”, but he talks about other uses a lot too.

Answer (score 4):

It is so old. It is also **so '80s-to-present**.

There is a usage of *so* that has become far more popular in the last 40 years, but "I'm so full" would not be an example of it. "So" has applied to adjectives since Old English: so old, so bold, so cold, so beautiful.

The recent usage involves applying *so* as an intensifier to nouns, other adverbs, verbs, or adjectives that customarily would not take an intensifier. Here's how the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/183635) describes it:

> a. Modifying a noun, or an adjective or adverb which does not usually admit comparison: extremely, characteristically.
>
> b. Modifying a verb: definitely, decidedly. Frequently in negative constructions.

*[The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English](https://books.google.com/books?id=qX5aDwAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA2013-IA198&lpg=RA1-PA2013-IA198&dq=%22Oh,%20please,%20you%20know.%20God,%20you%27re%20so%20the%20opposite!%22&source=bl&ots=WhRWznRase&sig=ACfU3U1wCQa1yV5LyEg8WSIcFVDTKNgNOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbm-aUmOngAhVFNd8KHbCJCyAQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Oh%2C%20please%2C%20you%20know.%20God%2C%20you%27re%20so%20the%20opposite!%22&f=false)*, noting the "attitude" and "pronunciation" with which this meaning is delivered, dates this usage to 1979 as used in the film *Manhattan*:

> Oh, please, you know, God, you're **so the opposite**!

"So" didn't usually modify nouns before this point. Here's [an example of *so*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/He_s_Just_Not_That_Into_You/92i6NTStSr8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=he%27s%20so%20not%20into%20you) applied to the colloquial phrase "[into you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97644/what-does-it-mean-being-into-someone)":

> He's made it clear that he's **so not into you** that he couldn't even bother to leave you a Post-it.

As for region of origin, the Oxford English Dictionary claims it is "chiefly US," and the first cited instance is from an American film.

Answer (score 3):

The OED has citations for that usage from old English until present. I think the problem is in intonation. If you imagine that the "so" with a sarcastic eye-roll, meaning "not at all" then I suspect, yes, the usage originated in California (specifically valley  speak) and is relatively (80s-90s) recent.

Edit you want citations:

Shakespere's much ado about nothing has: "That you haue such a Februarie face, So full of frost, of storme, and clowdinesse."

And here's another public domain citation from British English in [1819](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p-GVgEn3ohIC&pg=PA227&dq=%22become%20so%20full%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilwJiPwejgAhWTo3EKHb7IAmIQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22become%20so%20full%22&f=false).

And yet another example from the King James Bible, published 1611:

> Genesis 27:20:  And Isaac said unto his son, How is it that thou hast
>   found it so quickly, my son?

Those answer the OPs question, it's English usage from before America was a colony, let alone a country. As to the speculation as to why some other site thinks this is a modern Californian invention, without more information, the answer can only be speculation.

Comment: Equivalents appear in other languages (eg. Italian *così bello* = so beautiful) as well. Which suggests it is a very natural and/or ancient construction.